# Completely confused with my $PATH, iTerm, and ZSH setup

Tags: path, terminal, zsh

So I'm trying to add TeX Live to my PATH and I couldn't be more confused.
(For the record, I'm using iTerm and oh-my-zsh on Mac OS X)

In my `.zshrc` file, my path looks like this:

```
# Path to MAMP PHP
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin
# Path to LaTeX
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH
```

After adding the last two lines, my iTerm starts with errors looking like:

```
/Users/zach/.zshrc:17: command not found: killall
/usr/bin/env: zsh: No such file or directory
box_name:1: command not found: hostname
```

and more...

My `/etc/paths` file looks like

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

However, after ALL of this, `echo $PATH` just returns:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Please help me...I am getting so frustrated. All I want to be able to do is run `tlmgr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not included full .zshrc so hard to figured out what is going on, but I guess that in first line you rather want

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin
```

Otherwise you wouldn't be able to call any commands directly from e.g. /usr/bin, and messages like "command not found" only confirm my suspicion.

Comment: The rest of my .zshrc syntax appears to be fine, but I did notice this line at the bottom:

`export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"`

As of now, the three lines dealing with my path look like:
`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin`
`export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH`
`export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"`

Does that help you further?

Comment: I got it working! Here is what the lines look like now:
`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`
`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin`
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/bin/x86_64-darwin`

Thanks for all your help!